# Definition of measurable set in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I have read the following definitions for a *measurable set* $A$:

1. There exists a sequence of step functions (functions of the form $\sum_{i=1}^m a_i 1_{I_{i}}$, where $I_i$ is an interval in $\mathbb{R}^n$) such that it converges to $1_A$ a.e.
2. There exists a sequence of simple functions (functions of the form $\sum_{i=1}^m a_i 1_{A_{i}}$, where $A_i$ is a Borel set) such that it converges to $1_A$ a.e.
3. $A$ is a Borel set.
4. For all $B\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$, $m(A\cap B)+m(A^c\cap B)=m(B)$, where $m$ is the outer Lebesgue measure.

Which ones are equivalent?

**My thought**: $$ (2 \Leftrightarrow 3)\Rightarrow 1, $$
$$ 1\not\Rightarrow 3.$$
I would like to know if **$4\Leftrightarrow 1$**.

Comment: Borel sets are the smallest $\sigma$-algebra that contain the open sets, but there are more measurable sets than that. The last equation is Caratheodory's definition of measurability. Have you thought about the others?

Comment: @Pedro Tamaroff In probability I was proved that 3 implies 2, and also that 3 implies 4. Number 1 is the definition I used in a course of Lebesgue integration in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and I know that 3 implies 1. That's what I know.